# Razor Page dropdown

Tags: c#, dropdown

I am working on a .Net Asp Core Razor Page project and I want to have a dropdown and when I select one option of the dropdown it will be displayed on the input.

Here is the code for the dropdown:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="result">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> 
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu form-control">
            <select asp-for="MyList" asp-items="@Model.MyList" required="" id="selectedOption">
                <option value="" selected="">-- Select --</option> 
            </select>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code for jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#selectedOption').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $('#result').val(selectedValue);
         });
     });
</script>
```

The problem is that when I select an option from the dropdown, it is not displayed on the input field. Is there any other way I can obtain the desired behaviour?

**SOLUTION**

```
@section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#selectedOption').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $('#result').val(selectedValue);
        });
    </script>
}
```

I forgot to add the @section, now my code is working fine

Comment: Typo.  There's no variable called `$document`.  You meant: `$(document).ready(...)`  Side note: In the future you can observe this error by looking at your browser's development console.  *Always* look for errors there when something in your JavaScript code isn't working as expected.

Comment: Also noticed... You want to set the `.val(...)` of the target input, not the `.html(...)` of it.

Comment: @David you are right I am sorry this is my first app of this type. I fixed the issues you pointed out, but the input field still not displays the selected value.

Comment: If the problem is with the JavaScript, can you update the question to show the resulting client-side HTML?  You can even make the code into a [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to demonstrate.  For example, your code seems to work fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dh893sft/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code snippet:
Controller code for dropdown data

```
  var MyList = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "ONE" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "TWO" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "THREE" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "FOUR" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "FIVE" }
        };
```

Razor code:

```
<div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="result">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> 
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu form-control">
                    <select asp-for="MyList" asp-items="@Model.MyList" required="" id="selectedOption">
                        <option value="" selected="">-- Select --</option> 
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Jquery part changed to :

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $('#selectedOption').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $('#result').val(selectedValue);
         });
   </script>
```

Comment: I tried your code but still nothing happens. I have the dropdown with the options, but if I press one option it will not be displayed on the input

Comment: can you please add an alert(selectedValue); in your code like the following: $('#selectedOption').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            alert(selectedValue);
            $('#result').val(selectedValue);
         }); this is for checking whether your dropdown select works fine on change event.  One more point: can you please checkthe console for any error. If no errors then please share the dropdown data howyou defined in controller.

Comment: I have edited the answer with Binding details. Please check for data binding and selection also.

Comment: I tried your code but again nothing happens. I also updated my code with how I use the tag helpers and binding.

Comment: Also, I tried that option that you provided with the alert but nothing shows up.